# Tabulator | null verticalFillMode

Tags: tabulator

I'm moving Tabulator to Laravel and I get the following error when loading a sample testData:

```
tabulator.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'verticalFillMode')
```

I've fixed the row-height with *rowHeight:40*, but the error remain - and I didn't have to set it in the original code.

*verticalFillMode* is not a user settings -  could not find much about it online.

Any idea what could be wrong?
Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem.
Calling *setData*() when Tabulator was already loaded triggered the null error on *verticalFillMode*. Not sure why, but now it's working back.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#mp3_table", {
   data: tabledata,
..
});

table.setData(tabledata);  // this call triggered the error
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of tabulator are you making use of 5.6 ?  Trying calling the method like this('https://tabulator.info/docs/5.6/install')

```
 table.on("tableBuilt", () => {
 table.setData(tabledata); 
 });
```